# How do I implement nested #each blocks with Meteor and MongoDB reference?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

So, I have the following HandlebarsJS helper:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
      {{#each gralSkills}}
        <li class="pl-14"><i class="flaticon-checkmark4"></i> 
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{number}}">
            {{gralSkillName}}
          </a>
          <div id="collapse{{number}}" class="panel-collapse collapse small pl-21">
              <span class="block">{{gralSkillDescription}}</span>
              <span class="uppercase block">Indicadores - <a href="#" class="flaticon-plus34 text-danger not-underline" id="new-gral-skill-indicator"></a></span>
              <ul class="list-unstyled pl-14">                
                {{#each gralSkillIndicators}}
                  <li>- {{indicatorName}}</li>
                {{/each}}
              </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
```

With it's respective JS Code:

```
 Template.courseEdit.helpers({
      gralSkills: function(){
        var thisCourseId = Session.get('templateId');
        // console.log(thisCourseId);
        return gralSkills.find({"courseId": thisCourseId});
      },
      gralSkillIndicators: function() {
        var thisGralSkillId = Session.get('templateId');
        return Indicators.find({'courseId': thisGralSkillId});
      }
    });
```

The view looks like this:

[Screenshot http://soygus.com/img/emdinscreenshot.png](http://soygus.com/img/emdinscreenshot.png)

Which means that I'm getting both data into the view. The issue comes inside the loop, where I can't find how to reference the *Indicadores* to its respective parent.

Take a look to my MongoDB `Indicators` collection:

```
   /* 0 */
    {
        "indicatorName" : "La alumna presenta en clase con seguridad y confianza",
        // Belongs to a gralSkill (Autoestima)
        "gralSkillId" : "KgTAPKMeML2qWvsXA",
        "courseId" : "3vCN5v5brsid5tFGb",
        "_id" : "rpnkiRhdTMrsjgn7i"
    }
```

The only *Indicator* created belongs to the first list item in the view, however, I'm getting it displayed in all of the list-items.

This is the *gralSkills* collection for your reference:

```
  /* 0 */
    {
        "gralSkillName" : "Autoestima",
        "gralSkillDescription" : "La capacidad de confiar en las habilidades propias.",
        "submitted" : 1398089534856,
        "number" : 1,
        "courseId" : "3vCN5v5brsid5tFGb",
        "_id" : "KgTAPKMeML2qWvsXA"
    }

    /* 1 */
    {
        "gralSkillName" : "Emprendimiento",
        "gralSkillDescription" : "La capacidad de proponer soluciones con ideas y modelos de negocio",
        "submitted" : 1398094493828,
        "number" : 2,
        "courseId" : "3vCN5v5brsid5tFGb",
        "_id" : "zJGfgnZE8TMejQtWH"
    }
```

How can I make the list-items display its correspondent *Indicator*?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm getting this right, but I think in the `gralSkillIndicators` helper, it seems like you shouldn't be assigning the global Session variable `Session.get('templateId')` to `thisGralSkillId`, since that Session variable will be the same for all items of the loop.

Instead, you should write something like `var thisGralSkillId = this._id`, which should let you access the `_id` of the parent data context. If that makes sense?

Comment: Voila! Thanks, I didn't know that you can call the data of the parent context as easy as that.